TypeError: CellStyle.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'applyFillId'
Been banging my head with this error for a few hours now.
I am trying to read a xlxs file with pandas but i am running through this error.

TypeError: CellStyle.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'applyFillId'

Here is the code:
df = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name=_sheetname, skiprows=10, usecols=5, names=_columnnames)

  df = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name=_sheetname, skiprows=10, usecols=5, names=_columnnames)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 495, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(
         ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1567, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 553, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 573, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle, engine_kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 572, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 348, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 301, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 213, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 105, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtimothe\venv_new\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: CellStyle.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'applyFillId'

I tried specifying the engine in the parameter to openpyxl but gets the same error.
I expected to get a dataframe that reads the excel file with the specified columns and rows

What version of pandas? Does it support engine='calamine'?

pandas 2.2.2 and no it does not. I pip install python-calamine and when I run it, it throws ValueError: Unknown engine: calamine

Interesting, from the release notes it appears to be supported.
